# Embedding a Razor view inside another Razor view (same project)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In the default Asp.Net-Core template, I've created a new view (MyView.cshtml). The code for it looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "My View";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Stuff relating to My View goes here</p>
```

What I would like to do is to embedd this directly into the Home Index View.  I'm aware that I can do this:

```
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("MyView", Model);}
```

However, I've been looking at the [the Blazor story around this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and it looks much sleeker. Is there any support for this kind of syntax in Razor yet (and if so, how would I implement it - I tried what was on this link, but it looks like it's Blazor only)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual way you're supposed to do this is:

```
<partial name="MyView" />
```

`Model` is implicitly passed, so you don't need to do that explicitly. If you have something else you want to pass in instead, then you can do:

```
<partial name="MyView" model="@Model.SomeSubModel" />
```

There's nothing quite like Razor Components outside of Blazor. The fact that everything is running on the client makes possible a lot that otherwise wouldn't be. However, you *can* use [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2).